# history.push() not working when passed to other component fron functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am quite used to class components. There I can pass a function that is bound to `this` to other components without problems. I thought the same would hold true for functional components.

Yet, the following code simply does not work:

```
const Dropdown: React.FC<{onNewPost: any}> = (props) => {
    return(
        <div onClick={props.onNewPost}></div>
    )
}

function AddMessage(props: IProps) {
    const { conversationUUID } = props.match.params;
    const navigateToNewPost = (postUUID: string) =>  {
        props.history.push(`/app/messages/new/${postUUID}/`)
    }

    const onNewPost = () => {
        // props.history.push('/example/') -> this works without problems
        props.createPost(
            conversationUUID, 
            navigateToNewPost
        )
    }

    return(
        <Dropdown onNewPost={onNewPost}/>}
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({

})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
    createPost
}, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(AddMessage));
```

I think the problem arises because `props.history.push` is not bound to anything here but the `global object`? I think I am having trouble understanding how functions are bound in functional components ... Maybe some helpful soul can come up with an explanation. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
export const createPost = (conversationUUID: string, callback: any) => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res: any = authAxios.post('/posts/', {
            conversation: conversationUUID,
        })
        if (callback) {callback(res.data.uuid)}
    } catch(e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `createPost` function look like?

Comment: I edited it to the original post.

Comment: Oh, I see the error ... I forgot the await before the axios call ... so it just skips to the callback without having the value it needs ... my bad.